# How to make out of sample prediction in LSTM using Keras?

Tags: python, keras, lstm

In ARIMA, there is `get_forecast` method to predict the unseen future, for example:

```
results.get_forecast(steps=500)
```

Is there any built-in function in Keras for RNN/LSTM as well?

Answer (score 0):

No. I don't think there is. Keras is a framework not specifically targeted to time series prediction.

But you could implement this function yourself by creating a new stateful model from your existing weights with a single timestep and then predict the future values by using the prediction from the previous timestep as the new input.

Comment: Before posting my Q I had implemented that function and tried both stateful and stateless LSTM models, both work very well for in-sample prediction but very poorly for out of sample forecasting.